# Coverage report from istanbul looks weird

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, code-coverage, babeljs, istanbul

I'm using `istanbul`/`nyc` to generate a coverage report for a code base that I'm working with.  The code is written in ES6 and transpiled to ES5 using `babel`.  The specific test runner that we're using is `mocha`.

I'm generating HTML reports using the following command:

```
node_modules/.bin/nyc --reporter=lcov --require babel-core/register --require jsdom-global/register node_modules/.bin/mocha -R spec --ui tdd common/js/test/
```

Viewing the report is odd however.  For example, sometimes the report seems to indicate that a line is being hit many times (as indicated by the green square on the left hand side) but the line is still highlighted in red.

[image]

At other times, there are weird "holes" in the line highlighting:

[image]

What does this indicate?  Is there a problem with my coverage setup?

Comment: This [es6 coverage issue](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/284) might be of interest to you.

Comment: This isn't a great answer, but for anyone who stumbles across this, I've had better luck with `jest`...